# User Interface problem

Tags: jquery, user-interface

i have a user profile form in that i have four operations
1.view profile
2.edit profile infor
3.change password 
4.change profile picture

i want to  combine these operation into one and want to remove extra buttons 
how can i do it .

Comment: want to implement tab interface in this how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have remove the extra buttons and put the cancel which bring to profile view again.

thanks

rahul

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it, you are looking for [FormToWizard jQuery plugin](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/09/28/webform-wizard-jquery.aspx). It turns a long form into easy to use wizard with good interface.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell what you are asking for, if you don't give more details about your form. Usually for cases like the one you are describing, one will expect to see a single form with all the details about the user. The user should be able to edit fields by typing in text fields and overwriting the old values. For the picture there should be a "Change Picture" button close to the image. Finally, you may want to have a "Save" and a "Cancel" button at the bottom of the form.